# Is a dependency used by many packages?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

Can a dependency be used by many packages?

If this is true, for example, packages `A` and `B` use a common package `C` as a dependency, and now I remove package `A` using the `apt-get` command, will the dependency `C` also get removed?

Comment: no, since B depends on it but when you delete B you will get this message next time you use apt : "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required " then it will list all unused packages.
to delete unused packages `apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not true:

Package `C` will not be removed, because package `B` depends on package `C`. And also if you remove package `B`, package `C` will not be removed, if you don't use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

or a similar command.

Comment: But you will see a message (at least if you use `apt-get`, not sure about the GUI Software Center) that there are packages which were automatically installed as dependencies and are no longer needed.